# rails references: putting associations at bay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Good day to all,

Instead of doing the whole "belongs_to" and "has_many" relationships between directly related models, I connected them all by adding tons of references.

My understanding is that the only difference is semantical - however, semantics are very important, and given that I'm new to rails (and new to programming in general) and given that I have fallen in love with foreign keys ( <3 relational databases), I'm scared I might have tarnished my database (:gasp). In sum, I have 2 questions: 1. what are the downfalls to keeping it like this? and 2. how can I change it back?

I've experimented with changing it back through the following steps (for some of the migrations, not all - I wanted to have something to compare with) 1. removed migration file --> 2. added the appropriate belongs_to / has_many associations in the model file, 3. rails db:migrate. However, it didn't seem to change anything.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you say "references", you're talking about foreign keys in the db. To do things properly, you really need both the foreign keys *and* association macros. (belongs_to, has_many, etc)

The two work on different levels. The foreign keys set up the relations in your relational database, telling it that when queries come into the db, it can expect to use those columns to look up records on another table. (Actually, when using `.references` in migrations, all you're saying is that the database should create some columns on the tables whose names follow a certain pattern. Rails doesn't designate that these should be created as proper SQL foreign keys by default.) This to say that references only affect your database columns.

On the other hand, the associations you set up in your models tell the rails app how it can use the database to look for associated records. If you only use the associations, then any calls to the associations will break since it will rely on column that don't exist, and if you only use the references in your migrations, then although you'll be able to execute queries against the database, rails won't know how to do so.

Comment: Great answer! I never considered that "the database" and "Rails" worked as separate entities, although with hindsight it makes a lot of sense. "whose names follow a certain pattern" sheds light on why `rails db:migrate` was throwing errors when I tried to use an unconventionally-named primary key of one table (table "Annotation", pk: "selected", error: no relation "selecteds") to "add references" of that column as the foreign key of another table. I should manually add the foreign key myself inside of the migration file. Thanks again - un saludo

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you connected them all by adding tons of `references`, it sounds like that is in the migration whereas the `belongs_to` and `has_many`? Assuming that's the case, you really should use both. Having the foreign key in the database is absolutely the right design but you still need to have the associations specified in the model in order to tell Rails that it exists!

Comment: Gotcha! Didn't think about them both being an option. Thanks for the help!!